# Почему LSB ELF shared object можно изменять "на лету", а executable нет?

Tags: executable, elf, linux

Сразу предупреждаю, вопрос праздный, чисто от любопытства.

Известно, что работающий executable (например a.out) поменять нельзя

> bash: a.out: Text file busy

а с загружаемой shared library (.so) это проходит без проблем. Естественно, изменения для уже работающих программ будут видны только после `dlclose(), dlopen()`.

Поискал часочек в сети, но ничего не обнаружил. Поскольку (в данный момент) практического интереса вопрос для меня не имеет (просто интересно) лезть в исходники системы не хочу.

Кто-нибудь может объяснить такое различие в поведении системы (например, `fopen("a.out","a+")`) по отношению к этим (в общем, очень похожим (или тут я не прав?)) объектам?

**Update**

Могу предположить, что .so (аналогично Solaris) отображаются на swap, хотя в [Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10678) пишут:

> ...The filesystem cache, program code and shared libraries have a filesystem source, so the RAM associated with any of them can be reused for another purpose at any time. Should they be needed again, Linux can just read them back in from disk. ...

*Как гуру думают, это объясняет наблюдаемое явление?*

**UPDATE-2**

Про .so

Поскольку для .so делается mmap()  MAP_PRIVATE система по сути включает Copy-on-Write для .so страниц и при модификации страницы в файле отобразит ее на swap для каждого процесса, подключившего ее. Так что понятно откуда она подкачиваться будет (если потом потребуется).

Почему *text file busy* возникает с a.out, а  с .so нет.

В [переписке](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0110.0/0476.html) долго обсуждается флаг MAP_DENYWRITE и почему его нельзя разрешать устанавливать из user-mode. (а именно оттуда делается mmap() для .so). При запуске binary ядро этот флаг устанавливает.

Лично у меня сложилось впечатление, что достаточно было бы MAP_PRIVATE и для binary, также как и для .so, но спорить о вопросах безопасности Линусу не хотелось. На самом деле (практически) MAP_DENYWRITE для исполняемого a.out не мешает, но и не помогает (IMHO).

Важно, чтобы изменить код **уже исполняющейся** программы было трудно.

Пожалуй все, в данном вопросе я свое любопытство (**спаcибо** [[@northerner](/users/6536/northerner)](/users/6536/northerner) !) удовлетворил, но пока тему не закрываю. Возможно кто-нибудь захочет обсудить подобные вопросы в своих ответах.

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Солярис под рукой будет только завтра, поэтому на правах гадания: ELF - формат перемещаемого образа, a.out - нет. Следовательно, последний позволяет отображение непосредственно в DRAM. Проверочный эксперимент: попробовать открыть на запись главный модуль процесса в формате ELF.

Comment: @karmadro4, утилита file утверждает, что a.out тоже ELF.

>ELF (англ. Executable and Linkable Format — формат исполнимых и компонуемых файлов)

Comment: @avp, тогда моё предположение неверно. Что же касается a.out, то это (помимо нарицательного имени выходного файла от `a`) - legacy исполняемый формат, использовавшийся в System V (до появления ELF).

Comment: @karmadro4, именно так, исторически это был формат, как дань уважения нынче используется как имя исполняемого файла по умолчанию.

Comment: @avp, где-то видел переписку по этому вопросу с участием Линуса, попробую поискать

Comment: @northerner, если не сложно. 

Правда интересно, во первых *почему* разница, во вторых *как реализовано* для .so

Comment: Пока не нашел. Но если моя память не спит с другим, *почему* связано с вопросами безопасности, а *как* связано с флагами `mmap()`.

Comment: @northerner, cкорее дань не уважения, а традиции и обратной совместимости (в т.ч. и с документацией). Я сравнительно недавно видел образ IOS формата `a.out`, правда образ был не mainline, а особого назначения.

Comment: @karmadro4, возможно, к сожалению, мне ничего по этому поводу найти не удалось, [Википедия](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out) говорит только:

> a.out remains the default output file name for executables created by certain compilers/linkers when no output name is specified, even though these executables are no longer in the a.out format.

При этом ссылка ведет на переписку `gcc-help`, но и там причины, побудившие разработчиков оставить имя a.out для имени по умолчанию, не раскрываются.

Comment: @northerner, [вот например](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_3/configfun/command/reference/cfr_1g08.html#wp1042576)

Comment: Не очень понимаю, причем здесь разные форматы executable, но если интересно [вот нагуглил список](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats).

Про большинство из них никогда не слышал, но подозреваю, что для многих gcc по умолчанию создаст ./a.out (для формата **PE** он делает **a.exe**).

Answer (score 2):

Ага, вот вроде бы оно: http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0110.0/0476.html. Там довольно обширная дискуссия, сообщений сорок.

Comment: Я преобразовал Ваш коммент в ответ. Свой перенес сюда.

    Спасибо, ознакомлюсь.

Comment: Ознакомился, 2 раза перечитал. 

Что понял - в **update-2**.

Comment: Спасибо за краткую выдержку из этой дискуссии, да еще и на русском. И правда, может кому-то оказаться полезным.